# Python - Calling a function with (**dict)

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a function:

```
def a_func(name, last_name, bool = True):
   if bool == True:
       name = "Bob"
       full_name = name + last_name
       return full_name
   else:
       full_name = name + last_name
       return full_name
```

And this dictionary:

```
persons = { 
     person_1 : {"name" : "John", "last_name" : "Perkings" }
}
```

If I do a list comprehension the below way, it assumes that the boolean is True.  However, is there a way to use the **dict argument, but indicating the boolean as False?

```
a = [a_func(**value) for value in persons.values()]
```

Comment: Also, please don't name your variables `bool` as it already the name of a built-in function.

Comment: As indicated by Tomothy32 using names of existing elements is a bad practice of programming that can cause your program to behave indeterminately where the error is difficult to trace

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
a = [a_func(bool=False, **value) for value in persons.values()]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thanks.